# Re initialize bean in spring during runtime

Tags: java, spring, initialization, javabeans

I'm wondering if there is possibility to recreate a bean which was already created in java configuration on web app startup.

What I want to do is to reconfigure bean settings.

For example I create new bean with path to database:

```
     @Bean
     public TestBean getTestBean() {
         TestBean tb = new TestBean("some_path_taken_from_external_point");
         return tb;
     }
```

During runtime I want to change the path. Let's assume that this bean doesn't have the setter method for database path.
I will have some kind of event and a listener for this event. Listener should reinitialize TestBean with new path.

Is this possible?

I was thinking of some kind of wrapper. In such case I would have class TestBeanWrapper which will have method get() which will return TestBean instance and recreate(String path) which will create new object with given path.

I'm not sure exactly if such wrapper would work for me, as the TestBean is a class from external library, and I'm not sure if it's not injected somewhere (but probably it's not injected).

More possible is that the other beans may rely on TestBean, so they also must be reinitialized (in case if they won't have setters for my TestBean).

Is this even possible in Spring (4.1) ? What is the best approach for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still unsure why you would want to change the path but I have 2 suggestions:

**1. Look at setting the scope on the Bean.**
By setting the scope on the bean, you can regenerate the bean based on context.  Look at [Bean Scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) for more information.

**2.  Look at maybe using a controller or a service.**
Controllers and services allow getters and setters which may give you more control.

Comment: Path was only an example. This is just a configuration which I would like to manage during runtime. I don't want to redeploy whole app to update configuration. I know that it doesn't look correct, because such beans should have setters/getters, but those classes are not created by me, and not have those setters.  Bean with a scope is not what I'm looking for, as those beans are global.

@2 
Those classes are already provided by maven dependency, so I can't add to them setters or getters.

Comment: Ok... Have you looked at the controllers and services. \@Service is a great way to abstract you configuration from your model and view. In the past I've hosted a properties file behind a service to control the look and feel of my website. It can be easily accessed globally using the \@autowired annotation. Can you give a more relevant example of the getters and setters you were looking at using so I can think about it more.

Comment: yes I looked at them, but they won't resolve my problem. I want to recreate object, does two annotation won't allow me to do that without some magic. Those objects doesn't have getters/setters so the only way to provide new configuration is to recreate objects